# is it possible to get the"Properties" of a cell

Tags: excel, vba

Im trying to automate the marking of a 'test' spreadsheet. the student must do certain things like fill a cell with colour x and make column width = to y and set a border to z etc etc etc. Is it possible to use 'cell' function or similar to ask if cell(r,c).border= then true or cell (r,c).fillcolur=y then true etc..

•   the test example

On sheet 1 make the text of the title in cell C1 red, size 16, bold and change the font to Comic Sans. Then insert a new row after row 1 to create a space between the title and the information.
•   The range B3:C6 holds basic information about the party charges. Format the values in C3, C4 and C5 as currencies, displaying the £ sign and then format the titles in cell B3:B6 in bold and italic.
•   C6 tells you the percentage discount available if the party is over £100. Format the cell so that it displays the number as a percent, without any decimal places.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to programatically test and, if need be, modify the formatting of a cell. What has your research into the Excel object model revealed? This question seems like an attempt to use Stack Overflow as a replacement to Google search.

Comment: Agreed, you can do all of this. And you simply need to Google for them individually. Divide your requirement into steps and start one by one.

Comment: When you get to the point of writing code and get stuck, by all means ask a question. This question strikes me as premature, but otherwise reasonable enough.